# SQL getdate giving me issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following which is returning nothing, not even an error:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1)
  FROM table1
  WHERE col1 IN ('a','b','c')
  AND col2 IN (1,2,3)
  AND (col3 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
  GROUP BY col1
```

However, this works fine:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1)
  FROM table1
  WHERE col1 IN ('a','b','c')
  AND col2 IN (1,2,3)
  GROUP BY col1
```

How do I get it to work with the dates?  Basically I want to see results from 1 month back to today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

switch it

```
col3 BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

it is

```
some_column between lower_date and greater_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that BETWEEN is inclusive. If you don't want to include the border values use any combination of greater than (>) equal (=) and less than (<) operators.
example:

```
col3 >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) AND col3 < GETDATE()
```